# Are questions relating to musical analysis of anime songs on-topic or not?

Tags: support, allowed-topics

About a week or two ago I realized that Love Live's school idol music NEVER uses the diminished chord out of the seven [diatonic chords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(music)#Viennese_theory_of_the_degrees) in a key.

In major keys, the diatonic chords are:

> I / ii / iii / IV / V / vi / vii<sup>o</sup>

And in minor keys:

> i / ii<sup>o</sup> / III / iv / v / VI / VII

But the thing here is, that neither the vii<sup>o</sup> chord in major keys nor the ii<sup>o</sup> in minor is used in Love Live's music.  In minor keys, sometimes even that v chord is used.  Love Live tends to use both major and minor keys, and uses all of the diatonic chords EXCEPT for the vii<sup>o</sup> and ii<sup>o</sup>.

For example, in [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUvNP_BsU6E) in D minor, I hear:

> Dm, F, Gm, A, Bb, C (i, III, iv, V, VI, VII)

But I cannot find Edim (ii<sup>o</sup>) ANYWHERE in the song.

Also in [*Aishiteru Banzai*,](https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/misc-cartoons/love-live-school-idol-project-aishiteru-banzai-chords-1502626), you could definitely see E, F#m, G#m, A, B, C#m, but **there is no D#dim AT ALL.**

Now I am curious about is there a particular reason why Love Live does not use the diminished diatonic chord.  Will my question be on-topic if I post it on A&M?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Music theory is most certainly not on-topic.

Progressions using 
vii∘ (I–IV–vii∘–I and I–ii–vii∘–I) are less common because of the instability of diminished chords. The diminished tone dilemma you pose is encapsulated in [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/79438/are-the-diminished-chords-not-that-common-in-modern-popular-music) on music.se.

Comment: Without specific examples it's difficult to asertain the context. Either way, such discussions are not on-topic here. Please take it to appropriate site and provide proper examples to state your case and for comparisons. But know that it's likely going to be comparing oranges, tangerines, mandarins, and clementines to one another. Subjective, unless worded otherwise.

Comment: This is not a question we can reasonably answer unless we were the composers or coordinators for the series and franchise. Please do not use the comments to ask questions.

Comment: This and that are seperate matters.

Comment: No other site atm, unfortunately.

Comment: Is there any reason OTHER than the instability of the vii chord?  Add this to your answer, please.

Answer (score 2):

No, this would not be on topic on A&M.

This question would not be about Anime or Manga as defined in the scope in the [help center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help), as it is not about Anime or Manga, but about musical analysis.

Comment: Yes. One is an barely on-topic music identification question. The other is a music theory question. Scope and context make a difference even if they are related tangentally.